# Pattern match all subclasses in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, pattern-matching, subclass

I am using a third party library where exceptions result in a class of the type `RETCODE_ERROR`. This is a selection of the hierarchy.

[image: Return Code Class hierarchy]

Not being sure if the classes implement `Throwable`, I wish to pattern match against the super-class `RETCODE_ERROR`.

```
try {
  // perform action here
} catch {
  case e.asInstanceOf[RETCODE_ERROR] => // handle exception
}
```

Does this work, or is there a better approach?

Comment: `case e: RETCODE_ERROR => ...`

Comment: If they don't implement `Throwable`, it's impossible to throw or catch them. Judging from the name `RETCODE` (i.e. "return code"), they may be returned, _not_ thrown, in which case your code won't work.

Answer (score 6):

All kudos should go to @Jesper actually:

```
try {
  // perform action here
} catch {
  case e: RETCODE_ERROR => // handle exception
}
```

If you want to match against some **subset** of classes you can enumerate them nicely:

```
try {
  // perform action here
} catch {
  case e: (RETCODE_NO_DATA | RETCODE_ALREADY_DELETED) => // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using asInstanceOf is not recommended. Moreover, this code is not right.

> case e.asInstanceOf[RETCODE_ERROR] => // handle exception

Instead, you can use pattern matching like this:

```
try {
  // do something
} catch {
  case e: RETCODE_ERROR => // handle it
}
```

Comment: I guess, op just confused `asInstanceOf` with `isInstanceOf`